# String maniupulation in batch script

Tags: string, batch-file, batch-processing

I've got a script to retrieve PowerPath license information from arround 2k servers, I've automated this with simple script:

```
for /F %%A in (server_list.txt) do (
echo %%A >> PP_license.txt
psexec \\%%A powermt check_registration | find "Key" >> PP_license.txt
)
```

But I'm not happy with this output file, which now looks like this:

```
server1
Key XXXX-XXXX
server2
Key YYYY-YYYY
```

Is it possible to manipulate this to get output like:

```
server1 XXXX-XXXX
server2 YYYY-YYYY
```

?

If not then I'll try do this in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /F %%A in (server_list.txt) do (
    for /F "tokens=1*" %%B in ('psexec \\%%A powermt check_registration ^| find "Key" ') do (
        echo %%A %%C>> PP_license.txt
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /F %%A in (server_list.txt) do (
    (echo|set /p"= %%A ")>> PP_license.txt
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in ('psexec \\%%A powermt check_registration ^| find "Key" ') do (
        (echo %%x)>>PP_license.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Ok, that almost works :) But now the output is like this:

server1
key XXXX-XXXXserver2
key YYYY-YYYYserver3
key ZZZZ-ZZZZ

Comment: This comments give bad format ;)
So now I have:
server1 (newline) key XXXX server2 (newline) key YYYY,

What I want to get is:
server1 xxxx (newline) server2 yyyy ...

Comment: Despite you have your answer I've edited mine again.Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ren PP_license.txt PP_license.tmp
3<PP_license.tmp (
:loop
set /p srv=<&3
set /p key=<&3
if "%srv%"=="" goto :end
<nul set /p=%srv% >> PP_license.txt
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in "%key%" do set key=%%a
Echo %key% >> PP_license.txt
goto :loop
:end
)
```

And that **should** do exactly what you want.

Mona